# What is non LL(*) about this right-recursive Antlr rule?

Tags: context-free-grammar, antlr3

Consider the following Antlr3 grammar:

```
grammar stat;

s : 
  label ID '=' ID
| label 'return' ID
;

label
  : ID ':' label
|
;

ID: 'a'..'z' + ;
```

Given that Antlr3 is LL(*), which means the parser can look arbitrarily far ahead into the token stream when selecting an alternative, why am I getting the following error?

```
 [fatal] rule s has non-LL(*) decision due to recursive rule invocations reachable from alts 1,2.  Resolve by left-factoring or using syntactic predicates or using backtrack=true option.
```

**Question:**

1. How can I fix the above grammar? *(Explanation behind the fix would be greatly appreciated.)*
2. What is * in LL(*) if not backtracking after an unsuccessful, arbitrarily long lookahead, versus the static k of LL(k)?
3. Isn't automatic left-factoring something automatically done by Antlr3?
4. Curious, how could this also be fixed via use of syntactic predicates?

I'm using Antlr 3.5.2 .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This exact example (character-by-character) is found on page 277 of the ANTLR3 version of *The Definitive ANTLR Reference*, which is available on-line (at least for limited previewing as well as paid download). It's used as an explanation of one of the aspects of the LL(*) algorithm used in ANTLR3, so the explanation on the following pages is probably the best detailed answer to your question. In addition, various possible solutions are discussed.

So let me focus on just one of your questions, which I think will also answer the question in the post title.

> 2. *What is * in LL(*) if not backtracking after an unsuccessful, arbitrarily long lookahead?*

LL(*) is a heuristic algorithm and not a formal language category; Terence Parr (the author of ANTLR) uses the term to label a particular parsing algorithm used in ANTLR3. (ANTLR4 uses a different algorithm, which Parr calls Adaptive LL(*). I'm not goint to get into that.)

LL parsing, in general terms, decides which production to use before starting to parse the production. LL(k) parsing makes that decision based on the following k tokens, where k is some fixed (and usually small) integer. That was basically the algorithm used in ANTLR2, and it's not really good enough to handle many grammars.

To make the algorithm more general, you can add backtracking (which ANTLR does); if after examining k tokens, the parser still can't decide which production to use, it tries them in order until it finds one which works. If an attempted production fails, the parser returns to the decision point and tries the next production. If a production succeeds, the parser accepts it and continues, even if that might lead to a parsing failure later on. (So the order of productions in the grammar is important in a backtracking parser.)

LL(*) does not involve backtracking. Rather, it constructs a finite-automaton-based forward scan which matches an arbitrarily long lookahead sequence against a regular expression (of tokens, not characters, but the principle is the same). If it can construct (while compiling the grammar) regular expressions for each candidate production which unambiguously distinguish between the alternatives, then it can rapidly run the finite automatons in parallel at a decision point and make a decision. The * in LL(*) makes reference to the fact that there is no arbitrary length limit on the lookahead; it is only necessary that the regular expressions diverge at some point in the future.

As a practical example, in the grammar you present the alternative

```
  label ID '=' ID
```

should be chosen if the lookahead matches `(ID ':')* ID '='`, while

```
| label 'return' ID
```

should be chosen if the lookahead matches `(ID ':')* ID 'return'`. These are evidently distinct regular expressions; at most one can match any lookahead sequence.

However, all of that is dependent on the parser generator being able to work out the lookahead patterns. And that's a difficult (possibly impossible) problem in the general case. ANTLR3 does its best, but it cannot cope with recursive non-terminals (like `label`) in the lookahead sequence.

Since it can cope with repetition operators, you can fix the issue by simply changing the definition of `label` to a non-recursive alternative. (This comes straight out of the book referenced earlier.)

```
    label: (ID ':')*
```

That definition is already in regular expression form, and ANTLR3 can just plug it in to the production to produce effective lookahead patterns.

That's all probably just fine in practice, since long sequences of labels are not likely to occur in practice. But personally, I'd go for a simple LL(2) solution which doesn't use a `label` non-terminal at all:

```
s : 
  ID '=' ID
| 'return' ID
| ID ':' s
;
```

This solution doesn't require an unlimited lookahead search. And it still lets you insert arbitrary actions for each alternative.

Comment: Thanks. My key misunderstandings were: 1. Thinking star (*) meant backtracking and thus expecting backtracking to be enabled by default. 2. Assuming no implementation differences between DFA-powered patterns and recusive rules -- I thought Antlr3 would be doing some magic underneath to convert the syntactic-sugary EBNF patterns (that currently result in DFAs) into right-recursive rules! 3. Assuming left-factoring would be done automatically by Antlr3.

Comment: Would enabling backtracking be that bad an idea, given that Antlr3 memoizes previously tried rule fragments? A backtracking grammar would allow me to write grammars relatively more easily (possibly sloppily) keeping me productive. I don't expect to be encountering worst case often, and so don't mind a one-time sacrificing of a few cycles.

Comment: @Harry: The problem with ANTLR-style backtracking (or PEG, for that matter) is that it effectively turns alternation into ordered alternation, and that makes grammar a lot harder to analyse, both theoretically and practically. Ordered alternation means that some inputs which would otherwise match the grammar fail to be recognised. So there's an extra cost for sloppiness, to be paid in increased testing....

Comment: cont'd. When I write grammars, I've got four goals in mind. First, the grammar must be correct. Second,  must be easy to read, since it's part of the documentation, and easy to repurpose, since there will always be other tools to process the same language. Third, it should be reasonably efficient. And fourth, it should be easy for me as the programmer to maintain....

Comment: If I were writing a parser without a generator tool, I'd probably use recursive descent and try my best to only deviate from the model when strictly necessary (which will almost always be the case for some part of a real-world language). But in practice, I mostly use parser generators, and my preference is bottom-up, because it requires fewer compromises. If an LALR(1) grammar isn't easy to come up with, I'll go with GLR/GLL rather than uses hacks. (Well, not always. But the hacks almost always come back armed.)

Comment: I'm having a HARD time deciding on the parsing algo (and therefore the parser generator tool). I want to minimize the chances of running into a (near) deadend in future during grammar and/or SDT maintenance. I'd love to be proficient in all major grammar types and parser generators tools, but may likely not have enough of free time anytime soon. Was exploring Antlr3 (to be followed by Antlr4 for its ALL* algo and goodies like out-of-box support for visitor callback) -- part because of its general ease of use and part due to my mistaking the * in LL* for backtracking Lol.  ...

Comment: I'm guessing (for now) that the ALL* algo of Antlr4 will come close in power to GLR. Mr Parr, in his tech report (https://www.antlr.org/papers/allstar-techreport.pdf) lays out EMPIRICAL evidence (page 1, paras 5 and 6) for speed and other advantages of ALL*. It's things like these and lack of sufficient time to explore these algos and tools in detail that's leaving me quite depressed.

Comment: Writing a grammar for the lowest common denominator just to allow its repurposing for another tool means you aren't using the tool at hand and its power fully. What a mess! Handwritten recursive descent parsers would be the most fun but anything handwritten gets frowned upon by most bosses in most shops. Humiliating lectures on The NIH syndrome, the DRY principle :-) . My short-term goal is to be able to write compilers, translators, interpreters with a tool that's both easy to use and powerful enough. Was going with Bison and its G/LR algo initially but then changed my mind at the last moment

Answer (score 1):

In addition to rici's great answer I have a few comments:

1. <s>ANTLR3 is **not** LL(*), but LL(k), with a small number of k (and you have to specify k in the generation step, so it's not dynamic).</s> For each k level it creates a switch statement to determine a path, which can quickly lead to huge (and uncompilable) nested constructs. Hence k > 3 is usually not usable (and the lookahead is therefore not unlimited at all).
2. ANTLR3 can optionally use backtracking to improve parse accuracy.
3. ANTLR3 does not support direct left recursion - ANTLR4 does. Hence there's no automatic refactoring at all.
4. You cannot use recursion with a predicate from the parser generation standpoint, I think. The predicate will dynamically steer the parsing process and it might indeed solve the issue at runtime, but you won't get over the generation step anyway.

### Update

You might be right with your comments. I forgot that ANTLR3 does the lookahead during code generation (while ANTLR4 does that in the runtime). So, even though I am right with the result code (nested switch statements, one level for each k) I cannot really prove my claim about LL(k). And the [ANTLR3 documentation](https://theantlrguy.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/ANTLR3/pages/2687245/Grammar+options) says that the k parameter prevents the use of the acyclic LL* DFA.

As such this is just a complement to the accepted answer.

Comment: 1. I thought it's Antlr2 that's LL(k), with Antlr3 being LL(*). 2. Since Antlr3 memoizes its backtrackimg, maybe grammar writing can become more productive if I just turn backtracking on. Your thoughts? 3. Ok. 4. I've yet to study predicates.

Comment: I also thought that ANTLR2 was LL(k) and ANTLR3 was LL(\*). But I haven't actually used either of them :-(